# Syntax error on token ";" ... why?

Tags: java, syntax

why is there syntax error on this line ( shown below ) ? Thanks

```
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class Tokenizer 
{           
   public Tokenizer()
   {
   }        

   int n;
   String esempio = "Ciao dodo sos";
   StringTokenizer Tok = new StringTokenizer(esempio); // <---- Syntax error on token ";"

   while (Tok.hasMoreElements())
      System.out.println("" + ++n +": "+Tok.nextElement());
}
```

Comment: What method does that line belong to? None that I can see.

Comment: Is that code correct? The code in question is not within a function definition.

Comment: `System.out.println("" + ++n +": "+Tok.nextElement());` Please don't write things like that.. it is entirely unreadable. Increment `n` before and give `n` a better name.

Comment: Also, had you actually been using Netbeans or Eclipse, it would have shown this error before you tried to compile.

Answer (score 9):

The compiler is attempting to associate the `StringTokenizer` declaration with the `while` loop so is expecting an opening brace `{` (for anonymous implementation block) rather than a semi-colon `;`.

You need to use a method rather than have the code in the class block:

```
int n = 0;
String esempio = "Ciao dodo sos";
StringTokenizer Tok = new StringTokenizer(esempio); 

void doSomething() {

   while (Tok.hasMoreElements()) {
      System.out.println("" + ++n +": "+Tok.nextElement());
   }
}
```

A `while` statement is a non-declarative statement so it must appear in a method, static initializer or constructor.

Answer (score 6):

You need to write statements inside method, or some applicable code block

Answer (score 3):

What Reimeus said, plus a little more explanation on why you got the error on THAT line. With these two lines:

```
int n;
String esempio = "Ciao dodo sos";
```

you could have just been declaring class member data. When you actually tried to do something with the data, it became and error and needed to belong inside a method. HTH